# Clarification regarding wcf soap and xml

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap

I am currently using wcf for one of my project and before to this I have also used web service but I have some doubts which I want to clarify.

1) In web service communication we use soap for cross platform communication, but I like to know why soap is needed, as XML itself is universally acceptable data exchange format than why there is need of soap which internally uses xml tags for data exchange

2) If I use gethttpenabled for data exchange instead of mex protocol in wcf it generates simple web service proxy for communication so like to know if my service is using  nettcpbinding instead of basic or ws http banding so whether wcf and client can communicate or will create some issues.

3) As soap can be used with tcp protocol,  whether tcp protocol can be used for communication between different platforms that is client in java and wcf in net